# Why is the answer to this recurrence relation this?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value

(Cross-posted from math-SE for visibility)
self studying some probability theory and found this problem:

Michael Banks randomly selects cubes from Mary Poppins' magical bag (an infinite urn). In each random draw, a black cube is selected with probability $p$, and a white cube is selected with probability $q = 1 − p$.

For their magical task, Michael wants to have a sample with at least $b$ black cubes and at least $w$ white cubes. Let $S_{b,w}$ be the number of samples needed to ensure this. Clearly, $S_{b,w}$ is a random variable.

Your job is to help Mary and Michael derive a recurrence relation to compute $E[S_{b,w}]$ for any $b, w > 0$ and then proceed to do the same for the second moment $E[S^2_{b,w}]$ for any $b, w > 0$.

Now suppose there exists an upper limit to the sampling budget, i.e., Michael will stop sampling once he reaches his goal of $b$ black cubes and $w$ white cubes, or once Michael has collected $c$ cubes in total, whichever comes first. Let $S_{b,w,c}$ be the number of samples drawn. Derive a recurrence relation to compute $E[S_{b,w,c}]$ for any $b,w,c > 0$.

I'm pretty sure I have the first two parts fine. What I did for the first part was this:

$E[S_{b,w}] = \sum_{k = b+w}^{\infty}kP(S_{b,w} = k)$ and by the law of total probability (LOTP), we get

$E[S_{b,w}] = \sum_{k = b+w}^{\infty}k[P(S_{b-1,w} = k-1)P(S_{b,w} = k | S_{b-1,w} = k-1) + P(S_{b,w-1} = k-1)P(S_{b,w} = k | S_{b,w-1} = k-1)]$ which distributes into

$E[S_{b,w}] = \sum_{k = b+w}^{\infty}kP(S_{b-1,w} = k-1)P(S_{b,w} = k | S_{b-1,w} = k-1) + \sum_{k = b+w}^{\infty}kP(S_{b,w-1} = k-1)P(S_{b,w} = k | S_{b,w-1} = k-1)$ which comes out to be

$E[S_{b,w}] = \sum_{k = b+w}^{\infty}kP(S_{b-1,w} = k-1)p + \sum_{k = b+w}^{\infty}kP(S_{b,w-1} = k-1)q = [E[S_{b-1,w}]+1]p + [E[S_{b,w-1}]+1]q$. Thus, the final answer for this first part is

$E[S_{b,w}] = 1 + E[S_{b-1,w}]p + E[S_{b,w-1}]q. \square$ As for the second part, it starts like this:

$E[S^2_{b,w}] = \sum_{k = b+w}^{\infty}k^2P(S_{b,w} = k)$ and to save some space because the computations are largely the same as above *mutatis mutandis*, the answer actually comes out to be the same as for the first part (though I wouldn't mind if someone checked this for me). The algebra was pretty similar. I did a little substitution to change the index by one in the summation part to make things a bit easier but perhaps there was a better way.

Now where I'm completely lost and hopeless is for the last part. I've spent the last day or two to no avail trying to solve this last part. I don't know why I'm struggling with it so hard and would love someone to explain it to me. Someone gave me the solution which I know to be $E[S_{b,w,c}]=1+pE[S_{b-1,w,c-1}]+qE[S_{b,w-1,c-1}]$ but I don't understand how they got there or how you would start this problem. Thank you!